# Android Marshmallow runtime Permission at SplashScreen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I hit a wall during granting permission in marshmallow in splash screen.My motive is to that before loading the splash screen it should prompt user for permission.But,in my case,it do prompts but only for 2 sec then gets hidden.

**This is the code**

```
    public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    AlertDialog dailog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    int progressStatus = 0;
    TextView textView1, textView2;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    private SessionManager session;
    ConnectivityManager cm;
    boolean isConnected;
    private int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 23;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreen.this);
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }

        cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            setupWindowAnimations();
        }


        if(isReadStorageAllowed()){
            //If permission is already having then showing the toast
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,"You already have the permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Existing the method with return
            return;
        }

        //If the app has not the permission then asking for the permission
        requestStoragePermission();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(isReadStorageAllowed()){
            //If permission is already having then showing the toast
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,"You already have the permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Existing the method with return
            return;
        }else    //If the app has not the permission then asking for the permission
                requestStoragePermission();
    }

    //First permission before activity creation then it would undergo onpause then onResume check net
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        netValidator();
    }

    public void netValidator(){
        if(isConnected) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    forNext();
                }
            }, 2000);
        }else{
            showDialog();
        }

    }
    private boolean isReadStorageAllowed() {
        //Getting the permission status
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        //If permission is granted returning true
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return true;

        //If permission is not granted returning false
        return false;
    }
    private void requestStoragePermission(){

        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)){
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
            //Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "For Marsmallow,we do need this permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if(requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE){

            //If permission is granted
            if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){


                //Displaying a toast
                // Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted now you can read the storage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                // finish();
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                //Toast.makeText(this,"You have just denied the permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    private void forNext(){

        if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(session.getUserName()))) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,splash_Login.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
    private void showDialog(){

        builder.setTitle("Warning !");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setMessage("This application requires Internet connection.Go to Setting and Activate Internet");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));

            }

        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("EXIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                finish();
            }

        });

        dailog = builder.create();
        dailog.show();


    }

}
```

I would like to have prompt show before loading the splash screen.Could you help me where to make changes ?

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at this library. It makes things a lot easier. [PermissionsDispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher)

Comment: Musafa, Yeah I have read that but somehow I want this to be solved first.

Comment: Its a very bad design you are using though. Many loopholes in your design. And better it would be let animation done on splash screen and check if permission not granted then launch an Activity dedicated for to ask permission only and on permission granted MOve ahead otherwise exit.

Comment: Pankaj,I do agree on that,new to this, could you point me in code where I do have to change it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your method     **netValidator();**   from onResume and call it Here :

```
  if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

          netValidator();

        //Displaying a toast
        // Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted now you can read the storage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Also call this method where you are checking this :

```
 if(isReadStorageAllowed()){
      netValidator();
   }
```

In your onCreate() do like this :

```
  if(isReadStorageAllowed()){
    //If permission is already having then showing the toast
    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,"You already have the    
     permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    netValidator();
  //Existing the method with return
    //return;    Remove this
}else{

     //If the app has not the permission then asking for the permission
     requestStoragePermission();
 }
```

Comment: do I have to remove onStart() , and once I granted permission onSplash ,the next time I open app,it gets stucked on splash !

Comment: You dont need to check in onStart()

Comment: Thanks, It did help and one more thing, since here I added only 1 permission so how would I add more than one ?  int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

Comment: First use checkSelfPermission to check permission if not available then request using this method by  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE); and check in onRequestPermissions() using grantResults array